# Where to look for next rocket launches?

Tags: launch

Is there any place on the internet showing the upcoming rocket launches?

Like the launches next week or next month

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[nextspaceflight.com](https://nextspaceflight.com/)

This website is incredibly useful, providing a list of most upcoming launches with links to livestream and information as well as keeping a list of past launches (along with some additional things like Starship info and testing dates)

Additionally;
[spaceflightnow.com/launch-schedule](https://spaceflightnow.com/launch-schedule/)

Comment: They have a phone app too, if you want notifications for launches.

Answer (score 11):

Everyday Astronaut also has a great page for upcoming launches:

https://everydayastronaut.com/prelaunch-previews/

Answer (score 9):

[2020 in spaceflight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_in_spaceflight) on Wikipedia

You have to scroll down for *sub*orbital flights.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the information in a way more dense table format, you can also check out [nextrocket.space](https://nextrocket.space/).

Answer (score 6):

You can also check https://www.rocketlaunch.live - It also lists the last few recent launches.

Answer (score 3):

On the west coast, there's someone who maintains a mailing list called [Launch-Alert](http://mailman.qth.net/mailman/listinfo/launch-alert) announcing upcoming launches from Vandenberg AFB (and occasionally other things of interest like astronomical events).

Comment: Wow, that's old school. Reminds me of rare bird alert mail lists. I like it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Anymore I think 'old school' means, "That's how they did it last week, in the olden days." ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I find the Google Calendar "Worldwide Space Launches" very useful as it integrates with my existing calendars and notifications:  https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=msacpn523mpjgq0jlooh41eme4%40group.calendar.google.com

Comment: This is a great calendar. It is actively maintained and always up-to-date with the latest launch changes. I’ve been using it for a few years, but have no idea who maintains it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want super crisp, straight up launch schedule with links for more info and livestream, I might as well point you to the beautiful cards on my website - [Upcoming Launches](http://chandansinha.me/launch)

I built it using [Launch Library](https://launchlibrary.net) API which is really accurate. It's a WebApp, so just add it to your home screen and launch with a tap of a button whenever you want to know about the next launch.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://www.myspaceteacher.com/Upcominglaunches/ to have a look at upcoming launches.

This is probably a bit of a late reply but I came across your post now and want to start contributing more on space.stackexchange.